# Jest: I want to put test code under 'Project/test/' directory, but configuration error occured

Tags: typescript, module, jestjs, configuration, nestjs

I want to put my test code under 'Project/test/' directory, not 'Project/src/moduleName/'.

So I changed jest configuration at package.json.

1. rootDir

- "src" => "test"

2. moduleNameMapper

- "^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1" => "^src/(.*)$": "src/$1"

```json
"jest": {
    "rootDir": "test",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^src/(.*)$": "src/$1"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules",
      ".entity.ts"
    ]
  }
```

But configuration error occured.

> Configuration error: Could not locate module src/quests/quests.service mapped as:
> src/$1.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOY06.png)

How to fix this error? What I have to search? Or keyword?

Please recommend me some tips.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your root is in regards to `./test` but you try to say to find `src/*` as `src/$1`, which Jest interprets as `./test/src/$1`. You should do `"^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/../src/$1"` instead to map from the `rootDir` correctly

Comment: Thanks!!! I finally solved the error!! T.T Have a nice day!!! I apprecitate your answer, your kindness!!